# Nodejs + angularjs + mysql : How to render query data to angularjs using route/view

Tags: node.js, angularjs, view, routes, format

I'm using a mysql select query in my route and I'm trying to render the data in the view.

I have some trouble retrieving the data and display it with angular ng-repeat. I think it's something to do with the data format (json / array). If someone could light me a bit on this, would appreciate !

PS : I'm using EJS template

**Nodejs :**

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    var db_result = [];
    query = conn.query('SELECT * FROM table');
    query.on('error', function(err){
        throw err;
    });
    query.on('result', function(row){
        db_result = row;
        //Maybe I need to use db_result.push(row) or db_result = JSON.stringify(row);
    });
    query.on('end', function(result){
        res.render('index', { db_data: db_result });    
    });
    conn.release();
});
```

AngularJS :

```
//Code inside MainCtrl
$scope.db_datas = <%=db_data%>;

//HTML code

<div ng-repeat="db_data in db_datas | orderBy:'id':true">
    <p>{{db_data.id}}</p>
</div>
```

Edit :

The value of the nodejs variable `db_result` looks like this :

```
[ 
    {   id: 104,
        content: 'test',
        date: Sat Jul 26 2014 03:57:43 GMT+0200 (CEST) 
    },
    {   id: 105,
        content: 'test',
        date: Sat Jul 26 2014 03:57:43 GMT+0200 (CEST) 
    }
]
```

Comment: Well you are definitly right with the comment you provided - 'db_result.push(row)' is correct. Else you keep overwriting the variable and in the end you only have the last row inside of it.

Comment: Yes thanks. I still cannot get it work with angular, saying `missing [ after element list`. I really don't know what type of data need to be passed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass an EJS variable to an Angular ng-repeat filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081967/is-it-possible-to-pass-an-ejs-variable-to-an-angular-ng-repeat-filter)

Answer (score 0):

First of all do this

```
<div ng-repeat="db_data in db_datas | orderBy: idFilter: true">
    <p>{{db_data.id}}</p>
</div>
```

And then write the following code in MainCtrl

```
 $scope.idFilter=function(db_data){
    $scope.Id = db_data.id;
    return $scope.Id;
 };
```