# Is it possible to pass an EJS variable to an Angular ng-repeat filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ejs

I have a profile page that can render a user's name in plain text using <%= user.local.name %> - this queries the database using Mongoose. Is there a way I can pass that value to an Angular ng-repeat filter?

This works:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="x in users | filter:{'name':'Bob'}:true">
```

But this does not work:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="x in users | filter:{'name':<%= user.local.name %>}:true">
```

I know that 'Bob' is the value being rendered, because I display it elsewhere on the page. Does it have something to do with the variable being inside the brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap that value in quotes! (Else angular looks for `$scope.Bob`, rather than just `'Bob'`)

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in users | filter:{'name':'<%= user.local.name %>'}:true">
```

Comment: That worked! Could have SWORN I had already tried this way. Thank you!